# What are the main difference b/w ipad application code and iphone application code?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator

hey i am beginner in iphone application development.

i developed simple application in iphone but i also required it in ipad so for that i start coding for ipad but i didn`t get navigation properly in ipad code through

[self  presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

for that i use addsubView Method but it didnt get its navigation controller from viewdidload method.

and please tell me how much this type of diffrences b\w iphone and ipad applications.....

if thier is any tutorial on ipad appication than tell me..........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main difference between iPhone and iPad app is UI design, code behind the logic is same if you are using same components, there are some of the UI elements which are only iPad only like splitview, popup view as you start using these your code behind also changes.

you will get many samples on apple developers.